# Save image after modifying metadata

Tags: c#, image

I have a problem saving an image after having its metadata modified.
Basically, I want to open my image, display it, modify its EXIF metadata and than save it.

First, I had a problem trying to save my image because the original file was locked (I had a generic GTI+ error). After reading some posts here and finding what was the problem, I solved the lock problem with the using keyword.

But the problem is that if I use "using", the propertyItems list of my Image is empty and I can't modify my metadata.

Here is how I load my image (with different tests)

```
this.image = new Bitmap(this.path);         // this cause lock on file

/* the following doesn't lock the file, but image.propertyItems is empty */

//using (var bmpTemp = new Bitmap(this.path))
//{
//    this.image = new Bitmap(bmpTemp);
//}
```

Using streamReader or MemoryStream doesn't help...

And here is how I modify and save my Image:

```
 PropertyItem p = this.photo.Image.GetPropertyItem(0x5090);

 p.Id = 0x320;
 p.Type = 2; // Type ASCII
 p.Len = boxTitle.Text.Length;
 p.Value = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(boxTitle.Text);

 this.photo.Image.SetPropertyItem(p);
 this.photo.Image.Save(this.photo.Path);
```

Can you explain me why there's no propertyItems when I use "using", and how can I do to modify the image metadata's and than save it ?

Comment: It seems to work, but reading/writing metadatas for each picture causes performance problem with lots of pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to leave the original image alone after you read it, modify the property values, then save it as a new image. Apparently, Microsoft doesn't make a copy of the metadata in memory -- only the changes. So the original image remains locked in order to preserve the original metadata. To modify the metadata of an image, you save a new image and then replace the old one with it (or delete and rename).

Comment: I agree -- it's pretty dumb. The problem is that the image pretty much has to be re-written whenever the size of the exif data changes, because it's earlier in the file and has offsets, both absolute and relative. One other thing to consider is, if you rewrite the image using .net, you'll have to be careful or you'll end up with a lower quality. I believe imageMagick would be a better for this, if you want to use a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `Bitmap` constructor doesn't copy `PropertyItems`. You can copy `PropertyItems` between the images, and the release the file:

```
using (var bmpTemp = new Bitmap(this.path))
{
    this.image = new Bitmap(bmpTemp);
    foreach (var pi in bmpTemp.PropertyItems)
    {
        this.image.SetPropertyItem(pi);
    }
}
```

This still seems better than copying files.

Comment: As I said, it's a cleaner way to solve the problem but it doesn't work well in my case. When I have hundreds of images to load, it causes a real problem of performances. Moreover, there are side effects that need to be managed with this solution and not with the one of xpda

Comment: @thibon I understand. Unfortunately, didn't come up with anything better :) But I'm curious, how copying properties in-memory can be more painful in terms of performance than copying files?

Comment: It doesn't really copy them in memory. Even though bmpTemp is in memory, the metadata is not. That's why the file is locked. At least one disk access is required for each propertyitem, and they're saved in a fairly messy format.

Comment: @BartoszKP In my case, all my images are loaded at the startup of the program.
With your solution, for each file I copy the propertyItem in the unlocked image.
With the other solution, I create/delete/rename only the images where I want to change the property Item, and one at a time, which is transparent for the user. 
I hope I'm clear enough in my explanations